# ForEach element do promise to get a final sum angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set a counter of likes using facebook's GRAPH API. 
I have a list of object ids, and for earch ID, I use an api call to get how many likes this object got, then set a sum.

But this call is returning a promise, and when I'm using foreach, only one call is rearched even if I have more than one element in my list.

How can I do this to get this summation ? 
Here's my code.

```
countLike(data : any[]){
  let counter : number = 0;

  data.forEach(element => {
    this.debogger.debogSomething("Reached : " + element as string);
      this.facebook.api("/"+ (element as string) +"?fields=likes", ["public_profile","user_posts"]).then((response) => { 
        counter += response.likes.data.length as number;
        this.debogger.debogSomething(counter);  
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.debogger.debogSomething(err);
    });
  });
}
```

It's my first post in stackoverflow!
Thank you so much !

**[EDIT] new code, still not working **

```
countLike(){
  Promise.all(this.objectIdsToFilter.map((value) => {
    return this.facebook.api(value+"?fields=likes", ["public_profile","user_posts"])
  }))
  .then((response) => { 
    this.debogger.debogSomething(response)
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    this.debogger.debogSomething(err);
  })
}
```

In input, an array contains 3 values, (2 valids, 1 invalid). 
The output : nothing happens (weird, the debogger is a pop-up).

Comment: *only one call is rearched*: what does that mean? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely? And if data is an array of strings, why do you declare it as any[]?

Comment: Any[] it's just for intellisense, to get iterable methodes ...
I'm expecting for every string found in data, make an API Call, with facebook. I know that I receive two string (data has 2 strings inside), one is valid and the other one invalid. So I expect, that only the valid one make the counter higher, and the invalid one will raise the catch block. But when the invalid one is raised, the loop is like muted ... It's weird !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the new `async await` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if the promise concept is difficult for you.

Also there's this `async` module (https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) which you can use in js that has several methods such as `waterfall` which is exactly what you need, as the author says:

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try this asap, and come back with a feedback.

Comment: Perfect !! <3 Didn't knew about Async / Awaint keywords !!, But I guess, it makes the application more slower. 

Thank you so much for this !

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like below:-

```
countLike(data: any[]) {
    let counter: number = 0;

    Promise.all(data.map(element) => {
        this.debogger.debogSomething("Reached : " + element as string);
        this.facebook.api("/" + (element as string) + "?fields=likes", ["public_profile", "user_posts"])
    }).then((response) => {
        counter = response.reduce((sum, res) => {
            sum += res.likes.data.length ;
        }, 0);

        this.debogger.debogSomething(counter);
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.debogger.debogSomething(err);
    });

}
```

Comment: I used your Idea with the all() method, I understood the idea but it didn't work. I receive actually with the .all() property and array like this : "[null, null]" (data has 2 strings inside, that's normal). But I'm expectind something like : [ <jsonObjectWithError>, <jsonObjectCorrect> ]  ...

I'm still looking where I'm doing wrong...

Comment: The way Promise.all behaves is like it does not return any data if any of the call inside is rejected / errors out. Hence, all the calls should succeed and there is no way that one would succeed but the other would fail (by looking at your comment on the question). Are the calls that return the error send `200 Ok `status code?

Comment: Actually it always gaves me undefined object. Here is the new version of my code, using your idea, I'll put in edit ...

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are getting proper responses from the api in the developer tool's network tab?

Comment: I found a llitle mistake in my code, I do not need "/" in the URI. But still get [null, null]. After hours of trying, I found out that when I use Promise.all(), when there is a promise reject, the method is silenced ... I'm trying to implement a filter to know which promise is invalid, to remove it from array before apply Promise.all(). But It's not  clean at all :/ 

Actually, it doesn't work, nothing happens. (Look at edited code).

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? I thought you have already got one (the accepted answer)